# Default user key file for WLST

Tags: weblogic

When I start weblogic scripting tool (WLST) in the domain directory. I can connect using the following command without specifying the username or password.

```
connect(url="t3://localhost:7001",adminServerName="AdminServer")
```

I assume that WLST is using a default **userconfigfile** and **userkeyfile**, probably located somewhere relative to the servers/AdminServer directory.

1. Is this a correct assumption or is it using some other mechanism?
2. Is the userconfigfile being used "servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties"?
3. Where is the default userkeyfile?

Answers to these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a characteristic of weblogic - domain home configuration. If your current directory(pwd in Linux) is the same as the domain home, it will reach into the "secuirty/AdminServer" folder and use the contents of the boot.properties with the combination of the SerializedSystemIni.dat to log you in. Should either one of these not be present, you will not be able to do that. The default key file is the "DefaultAuthenticatorInit.ldift" but that is just the password safe so sorts.